# Why Qt designer don't show the option "View Python code"

Tags: python, qt-designer

Why Qt designer doesn't show the option "View Python code"? There is only "View code".

[image]

Comment: My guess is you have an old version of Qt Designer. View Python Code shows up in my version (5.15.3) on the Form menu.

Comment: I can't see QT Designer this version 5.15. Can you send the link, please?

Comment: 1. you should double check you have version 5.15 in Designer (Help...About Qt Designer). 2. On my View menu, I have View C++ Code... and View Python Code ...

Comment: I have 5.11.1. But I downloaded the program from official site. I didn't find ur version. Can u send the link to this version?

Comment: bfris, can you help me with the link?

Comment: The recommended way of installing both PyQt5 and pyside2 is via pip using the command line e.g. `pip install PyQt5`. If you have a problem with pip, you'll need to cd into your Python\Scripts directory and run from there. I'm not sure about pyside2, but PyQt5 ships with Qt Designer. Finally, a word of caution: if you are planning to use Designer as an IDE, I think you will be very disappointed. Qt Creator (the official Qt IDE) has made great strides in Python support, but most people still seem to use other editors (PyCharm, Geany, VSCode, etc.)

Comment: Correction. The pip version of PyQt5 does not include Designer. For that, you'll need `pip install pyqt5-tools`

Answer (score 0):

for PySide6, copy `uic.exe` to `<yourPythonRoot>/Lib/site-packages/PySide6/bin/` then relaunch designer.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DnaHg4M_AM&t=231s